# Ellipsoid moment of inertia matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, classical-mechanics, elliptic-integrals

Some background info: torque $\tau$ is defined as $$\tau = I*d\omega$$

Where $I$ is the moment of inertia matrix and $d\omega$ is an object's rotational acceleration. As I understand it, the inertia matrix acts just like mass in that it counteracts the torque (for example, if an object is spinning around the x axis, a big value of $I_{xx}$ means that the object needs more torque around the x axis in order to spin).

However, angular momentum $M$ can be defined as $$M=I * \omega$$

Where $\omega$ is the rotational velocity. So it seems that torque is the time derivative of angular momentum.

Using these facts, how would I find the moment of inertia matrix for an ellipsoid with uniform density of the form $$\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}+\frac{z^2}{c}≤9$$ with $a≠b≠c≠0$? Would I have to use spherical coordinates somehow? I'm not given any torque or angular velocity information. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node64.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In usual notation, 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} &= 1 \\
  I_{ij} &=
  \iiint \rho(\mathbf{r}) (r^{2} \delta_{ij}-x_{i} x_{j}) d^{3} \, \mathbf{r} \\
  I &= \frac{m}{5}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    b^2+c^2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & c^2+a^2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & a^2+b^2 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

In your case: $$I=\frac{3m}{5}
\begin{pmatrix}
    b+c & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & c+a & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & a+b \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

See also the link [here](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/MomentofInertiaEllipsoid.html).

**P.S.:**

By symmetry, $i\neq j \implies I_{ij}=0$

Let $x=a X$, $y=b Y$ and $z=c Z$

\begin{align*}
  \iiint_{x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2<1} x^{2} dV &=
  abc \iiint_{X^2+Y^2+Z^2<1} a^{2} X^{2} dX dY dZ \\
  &=
  abc\int_{-1}^{1}
  \left[
    \int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2}}
    \left( \int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}} dZ \right)  dY
  \right] a^2X^2  dX \\
  &= 
  abc\int_{-1}^{1}
  \left[
    \int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2}}
    2\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2} dY
  \right] a^2X^2  dX \\
  &= abc\int_{-1}^{1} \pi (1-X^2)  a^2X^2  dX \\
  &= \pi abc \times \frac{4a^2}{15} \\
 \rho &= \frac{3m}{4\pi abc} \\
  I_{11} &= \rho \iiint (y^2+z^2) dV \\
  &= \frac{m}{5} (b^2+c^2)
\end{align*}

Finish the rest by symmetry.

Comment: Don't you mean $z^2$ for the third term?

Comment: @JimM Typo corrected

Comment: How do you evaluate this triple integral?

Comment: See *PS* in answer

Comment: Also, once you do the substitution that reduced the integral to a sphere, you can finish with spherical coordinates and eliminate most of the work (instead of a triple horror of square roots), or just "steal" the known answer from the sphere.

Comment: Here, I can switch the role of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ freely, but **spherical polar coordinates**, there're trigos in $\theta$ and $\phi$ (see the link in the answer).  Though I converted into **reduced sphere** but still in **Cartesian**.